# Using Abstract class in html template

Tags: angular, typescript, abstract-class, angular8

I have created an Abstract class to store all the constants

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()  
export abstract class Constant{
    public static VIEW_REPORT:string="viewReport";
    public static CREATE_REPORT:string="createReport";
}
```

and I want to use these constants in html , like

```
<viewReportSel *ngIf="loadedFeature === constant.VIEW_REPORT"></viewReportSel>
```

I have imported the constant in corresponding .ts file. but getting error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'VIEW_REPORT' of undefined

Comment: did you extend your class Constant ?

Comment: Can you show me the code of the component viewReportSel. And did you extend your class with the abstract class?

Comment: Nope. I did not extend the class. Want to use as static class. if i remove abstract and create instance it works fine. Thanks Jazib and Fasco

Answer (score 1):

From the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes):

> Abstract classes are base classes from which other classes may be derived. **They may not be instantiated directly.**

So, when you are importing your `Constant` abstract class, you are importing a class definition which must be extended by another class in order to be used.

You can use a normal class to define your constants, and use the `readonly` keyword to make sure they cannot be overwritten (an error will be thrown if an attempt to overwrite them is made, even if it is in the class's own constructor). The class does not need to be made injectable and can just be imported and used directly.

```
export class Constants {
  public static readonly VIEW_REPORT:string = "viewReport";
  public static readonly CREATE_REPORT:string = "createReport";
}
```

Then you can use it in your templates component class using:

```
import { Constant } from './constant.ts';
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
    public constant = Constant;
}
```

Comment: thanks. when i try to use in html template i get this error    ERROR in src/app/app.component.html(17,27): : Property 'VIEW_REPORT' is a static member of type 'Constant'

Comment: The Constant class will need to be assigned to a property of your component so that the template can access it. The template can only access fields and methods of the component class. I've updated my answer to show this.